# Facebook get developer account email?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I am using "Log in with facebook" feature in my prod for which I have public and private key. Suddenly My request is failing with error `Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app.` The person who did set up this account left the company. Now I don't even know username and password what I have is only public and private/secret key . Is there a way I can get username or password or both with private/secret key ?

Even if i get dev username/email, I can try to catch that person.

Comment: Of course not. You have to reach out to Facebook to get back the app.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/app/roles could get you their user id at least, if you combine app id and secret, separated by a pipe symbol, to form an app access token. Problem is, that app-scoped user id won’t allow you to access their profile, by appending it to facebook.com/userid or anything. But if you make a request for that user id again, using the app token, you might get their name at least.